# weblogic hot deployment working for jsps but not for web-inf/classes

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, hotdeploy

I am deploying an ear application in weblogic 10.3 in exploded format with fast swap enabled and in dev mode.
The ear file contains a web app also in exploded format. The changes made to the jsps in the web app are getting reloaded. But the classes under web-inf when changed are not reloaded.

The weblogic deployment configuration is given below. 
weblogic-application.xml content in ear/META-INF

```
<wls:fast-swap>
    <wls:enabled>true</wls:enabled>
    <wls:refresh-interval>10</wls:refresh-interval>
    </wls:fast-swap>
<wls:classloader-structure>
        <wls:classloader-structure>
            <wls:module-ref>
                <wls:module-uri>web.war</wls:module-uri>
            </wls:module-ref>
        </wls:classloader-structure>  
</wls:classloader-structure>
```

application.xml content in ear/META-INF

```
    <display-name>web-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>web.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
```

weblogic.xml content in war/WEB-INF

```
<wls:fast-swap>
        <wls:enabled>true</wls:enabled>
        <wls:refresh-interval>10</wls:refresh-interval>
</wls:fast-swap>

<wls:context-root>/web</wls:context-root>
<wls:session-descriptor>
        <wls:cookie-max-age-secs>-1</wls:cookie-max-age-secs>
        <wls:cookie-name>JSESSIONID_SQE_AAI</wls:cookie-name>
        <wls:cookie-path>/</wls:cookie-path>
        <wls:cookies-enabled>true</wls:cookies-enabled>
        <wls:invalidation-interval-secs>120</wls:invalidation-interval-secs>
        <wls:id-length>52</wls:id-length>
        <wls:timeout-secs>7200</wls:timeout-secs>
        <wls:url-rewriting-enabled>true</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
        <wls:persistent-store-type>memory</wls:persistent-store-type>
        <wls:http-proxy-caching-of-cookies>false</wls:http-proxy-caching-of-cookies>
    </wls:session-descriptor>
    <wls:jsp-descriptor>
        <wls:page-check-seconds>6</wls:page-check-seconds>
    </wls:jsp-descriptor>
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:servlet-reload-check-secs>6</wls:servlet-reload-check-secs>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Is the configuration done above right? Are there any config details I have missed to include here? What other settings or configurations should I check?
Any help would be very much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you enable FastSwap in your application, the modules that are declared in the classloader-structure will not support FastSwap because they aren't loaded by the RedefiningClassLoader, but rather by the GenericClassLoader.
You can test this by printing the classloader of your classes under WEB-INF/classes and check if it's the com.bea.wls.redef.RedefiningClassLoader or not.

I struggled to make them work together, you can see more details here https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2476484&tstart=60 but, unfortunately, no solution so far.

Regards.